# Put part of a git submodule to different location

Tags: python, git, git-submodules

I would like to use `git submodule` to include another Python library into my application. The only problem is, that I need the actual module to go into a special location from which I can load it. I already thought about a script that would simply copy the contents I need from the submodule to the location it needs to be, but I was hoping that there is already an existing solution.

It would be nice if the contents from the submodule I need in a different location would automatically be synced when the submodule is updated. Let me finally give a short illustration to the problem I have:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:nr-python/nr.async.git vendor/nr.async
cp vendor/nr.async/src libs/nr.async.egg
```

Now if I update the submodule, I would need to copy the contents *again*.

```
cd vendor/nr.async && git pull origin master && cd ../..
rm -r libs/nr.async && cp vendor/nr.async/src libs/nr.async.egg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the worktree for a repo anywhere you like -- and you can put the repo for a worktree anywhere you like.

To configure the worktree for a repo, do

```
git config core.worktree /path/to/worktree
```

To configure the repo path for a worktree, put the repo where you want (and named anything you want) and do

```
echo gitdir: /path/to/repo >/path/to/worktree/.git
```

You can also override the paths git will find via the filesystem using environment variables `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`.

Comment: That doesn't allow me to use only a *part* of the work tree, does it?

Comment: No, that's correct, git has nothing built in for that.  You can get that effect with sparse checkout and a post-checkout hook that does a subsidiary read-tree. It does mean a few lines of scripting, but ordinary checkout would drive the whole thing automatically once it's set up.